# Installed a new remote-control fan, now wall switch doesn't control lights anymore

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan, fans

I just got the Parrot Uncle F4503Q model, a remote control fan unit, and I have installed it.

After installing the unit, I turned on the circuit breaker and the lights turned on perfectly, but now I notice my switch on the wall does not work.
I can flip it on and off and my lights on the fan will stay on - the switch has no effect on the unit. The only way to turn it off is by using the remote.

When installing the wires from the receiver to the wires in the ceiling, I connected 1st wire white to white and the 2nd color from the receiver is red I connected that to black, which in the diagram says red or black. I do have a red wire from the ceiling as well, which I capped off on its own.

Should I change the connection of the red wire and black wire to red and red and leave the black wire from the ceiling capped off alone to have my switch working again?

It's my first time changing a fan, I really appreciate all the help and assistance I can get. Thank you.

[image: diagram of fan unit]

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of all boxes involved please?

Answer (score 4):

If you want the fan controlled by the remote and the lights controlled by the wall switch, then you need to deviate from the pictured diagram a little.

The fan remote appears to also control the light if wired per the diagram (always-on power, probably the ceiling black, to the remote, then the remote to the fan and lights).

To have the fan on remote and the lights on the wall switch, wire the ceiling black and white per the diagram to the remote, and the fan power to the remote output black and fan/light white return to the remote output white.

However, wire the light's power wire directly to the ceiling red, not to the remote's blue output. Cap the remote blue output, it won't be used.

Red will provide switched power to the lights directly, and black provides always-on power to the remote to handle the fan only.

Answer (score 2):

The black, red and the white wire in the ceiling is the normal setup for a fan to have the lights switched on and off by the wall switch and the fan to be controlled by the pull chain. The black wire from the ceiling will be your always hot and not be affected by the switch. The red wire will be controlled by the switch. So if you want the fan and lights to be controlled by the switch, connect the red or black wire from the receiver to the red wire from the ceiling and cap the black.

Comment: Wouldn't this leave the reciever on switched power, meaning the rmote will be useless unless the light is on?

Comment: @GOATNine  Yes it would. the remote would be useless unless the switch was on. When the switch is on, the remote controls everything which is why they buy a remote unit. When they exit the room at night, they might not want to leave in the dark so that's why they might want to have a wall switch shut down the unit.